# More concise way of filling blocks of NaN values with CAGR between beginning and ending periods with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Sample data:

```
data = {'year':[2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        'revenue' : [100, np.nan, np.nan, 108, 118, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 127, 135]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')
df
```

Output:

```
        revenue
year    
2011    100.0
2012    NaN
2013    NaN
2014    108.0
2015    118.0
2016    NaN
2017    NaN
2018    NaN
2019    127.0
2020    135.0
```

I would like to fill in each NaN value corresponding to the Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) of the first and last known periods that it is contained within. By using the [following equation](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cagr.asp) to calculate CAGR of the 2 blocks of NaN values pictured:

```
growthA=((df.loc[2014,'revenue']/df.loc[2011,'revenue'])**(1/len(df.loc[2011:2014])))

growthB=((df.loc[2019,'revenue']/df.loc[2015,'revenue'])**(1/len(df.loc[2015:2019])))
```

Note: I left out the -1 so I can just multiply each iteration by my growth variables.

Now I can fill in the NaN values as follows:

```
df.loc[2012, 'revenue'] = df.loc[2011, 'revenue'] * growthA
df.loc[2013, 'revenue'] = df.loc[2012, 'revenue'] * growthA

df.loc[2016, 'revenue'] = df.loc[2015, 'revenue'] * growthB
df.loc[2017, 'revenue'] = df.loc[2016, 'revenue'] * growthB
df.loc[2018, 'revenue'] = df.loc[2017, 'revenue'] * growthB

df
```

Yielding my desired output:

```
        revenue
year    
2011    100.000000
2012    101.942655
2013    103.923048
2014    108.000000
2015    118.000000
2016    119.747471
2017    121.520820
2018    123.320431
2019    127.000000
2020    135.000000
```

This works, but isn't very efficient when working with a much larger dataset for obvious reasons. My goal is to write a script that automates filling multiple blocks of NaN values in the fashion I have shown, without having to go year by year within each block of NaNs, and going block by block across the entire dataset.

What would be a good place to start to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to interpolate data in your DataFrame. From what I understand, you want to apply a kind of exponential growth rate between each date.

As `pandas` does not have direct exponential interpolation, an idea would be to first apply a `log` (understand it as natural logarithm, or `ln` in maths) function to your `revenue` column, apply a linear interpolation, then putting back the `exponential` to see the `nan` values filled with the interpolation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'year': [2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020],
        'revenue': [100, np.nan, np.nan, 108, 118, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 127, 135]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('year')

df['revenue2'] = df['revenue'].apply(np.log)
df['revenue2'] = df['revenue2'].interpolate('linear')
df['revenue2'] = df['revenue2'].apply(np.exp)
```

[image: Here is the DataFrame I get]

By checking closely this does not seem to fit exactly your desired output, but it is very close.

Hope this helps